# Как убить другую функцию

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

У меня есть функция, которая делает запрос к VK API при завершении видеоролика:

```
 video.addEventListener('ended', example);
 var example = function () {
   VK.api('video.get', { owner_id: 123 }, function(data) { 
     /**...*/ 
   }
 }
```

Есть кнопка Replay, на которую пользователь может нажать быстрее, чем придет ответ от апи. В таком случае нужно убить запрос. Какими способами я могу это сделать?

Comment: убить ты его не убьёшь, может, проще заблокировать реплей при отправке своего запроса?

Answer (score 1):

Быстро же, однако, надо действовать, чтобы запрос обогнать :)
Отменить вроде нельзя (с VK API не знаком точно, может и можно), но это и не нужно - просто в callback-функции проверяешь на нажатие этого самого "Replay" и, если нужно, делаешь `return;` - это прервёт функцию.
P. S. "Убить" функцию до окончания запроса не выйдет, ибо она не запущена - колбэк запуститься только после получения ответа, а как после этого убить я написал выше.

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте удалять и снова создавать EventListener
[RemoveEventListener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp)

Comment: вообще не в тему, вопрос явно о том, как прервать вызов апи...